# PenAlignment.Outset has no effect

Tags: .net, graphics, drawing

I'm drawing a rectangle with Pen.Alignment = PenAlignment.Outset onto a PictureBox (which has a green background).

This is the code:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint

    Dim iTop As Integer = 1
    Dim iLeft As Integer = 1
    Dim iRight As Integer = 3
    Dim iBottom As Integer = 3

    Dim r As Rectangle = Rectangle.FromLTRB(iLeft, iTop, iRight, iBottom)

    Using nPen As Pen = New Pen(Color.Black)
        nPen.Alignment = PenAlignment.Outset
        e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel
        nPen.Width = 1
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(nPen, r)
    End Using

End Sub
```

However, the PenAlignment doesn't have any effect.
This is the output:

[image]

Instead of drawing the rectangle with "outset", it draws exactely where the rectangle is. I expect the black lines to be drawn just around the rectangle.

So the first black point should be at 0-0, not at 1-1.

What might be going wrong here?

Comment: I don't see any mistake in the code. Well, that's strange. :-/

Comment: I believe the Pen.Alignments are used when the width of the Pen is greater than 1.  If you want to draw a bigger rectangle, you will have to resize it yourself.

Comment: I don't see that mentioned in the MSDN. Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and got no answers so I had to work around it.

Here's what I did:

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint

    'Main Shape Values
    Dim x = 100
    Dim y = 100
    Dim wdth = 300
    Dim hght = 200
    Dim shP = 2

    'Main Shape
    Dim ShapePen As New Pen(Color.Black, shP)
    Dim Shape As New Rectangle(x, y, wdth, hght)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(ShapePen, Shape)

    'Values For the Alignment
    Dim P_Thck = 20
    Dim R_ThickL = (P_Thck / 2) + (shP / 2)
    Dim R_ThickS = R_ThickL * 2

    Dim AlignmentPen As New Pen(Color.Red, P_Thck)
    'Dim Align_Outset As New Rectangle(x - R_ThickL, y - R_ThickL, wdth + R_ThickS, hght + R_ThickS)
    Dim Align_Inset As New Rectangle(x + R_ThickL, y + R_ThickL, wdth - R_ThickS, hght - R_ThickS)

    'e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(AlignmentPen, Align_Outset)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(AlignmentPen, Align_Inset)

End Sub
```

I use two shapes.
One is my working shape and the other is the one I adjust for my alignment graphics.

[Inset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thegi.jpg)

[Outset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuRri.jpg)